# Struggling to install jenssegers/mongodb 3.6 for Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to install the package for working with mongodb, but getting these problems with packages:

```
pavel@pavel:~/Project/$ ../../composer.phar require jenssegers/mongodb
Using version ^3.6 for jenssegers/mongodb
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - amirhb/laravel-mongodb-log 1.2 requires jenssegers/mongodb 3.4.5 -> satisfiable by jenssegers/mongodb[v3.4.5] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - amirhb/laravel-mongodb-log 1.2 requires jenssegers/mongodb 3.4.5 -> satisfiable by jenssegers/mongodb[v3.4.5] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - amirhb/laravel-mongodb-log 1.2 requires jenssegers/mongodb 3.4.5 -> satisfiable by jenssegers/mongodb[v3.4.5] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for amirhb/laravel-mongodb-log (locked at 1.2, required as ^1.1) -> satisfiable by amirhb/laravel-mongodb-log[1.2].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

How to eliminate them?

Answer (score 0):

It means that you have installed a package named `amirhb/laravel-mongodb-log v1.2` which requires `jenssegers/mongodb 3.4.5` but you are trying to install `jenssegers/mongodb 3.6` which makes them to conflict in version what you can do is either install a higher version of `amirhb/laravel-mongodb-log` or install `jenssegers/mongodb 3.4.5` and NOT the `3.6` one